# NameError: uninitialized constant on Module being called

Tags: ruby, irb

I am trying to test run a little gem I am building out through IRB. I am running: `test = Test::Client.new(token: xxx)`. I get this error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Test`. Can you please point me in the right direction. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

module Test
  class Client
    include HTTParty
    API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.example.com/v1"
    def initialize(options={})
      self.class.base_uri API_ENDPOINT
      self.class.headers "Accept" => "application/json", "authorization" => "Bearer #{options[:token]}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It should raise a different error.

Comment: Have you required the file first?

Comment: After closing the quoted `API_ENDPOINT` string, it works. Perhaps you need to be clearer in how your are running this. Is the above code pasted into irb, or are you placing it into a file? If the latter, you will need to require that file so that `Test` is initialized.

Comment: @RayBaxter I loaded the file into irb itself. e.g. `>> load ./example.rb`. But I am still getting the same error. Any pointers? Thanks for looking into this.